# How to add a COUNT column to a working query with group() in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count

I have a list of UserProfile which may (or may not) have one or more widgets:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
end

@all_profiles = UserProfile.joins(:widgets).group('user_profiles.id').order("name ASC")
```

In the index view, instead of doing a new query in EACH line of the view to get the count of widgets for `@all_profile.each`, is there a way to add a count column to the original that shows how many widgets were in each grouped row? (Eg, avoid re-querying the database N times if there are N @all_profiles ?

(this is important not only to avoid N extra queries, but it allows us to add a SORT option on the count column so we can sort by customers with the most widgets)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a `COUNT` column via [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select)

```
@all_profiles = UserProfile.joins(:widgets).select('user_profiles.*, COUNT(*) AS widget_count').group('user_profiles.id').order('name ASC')
```

Now, each of the returned objects will contain a `widget_count` attribute that you can access just like any other model attribute:

```
@all_profiles.each do |profile|
  puts profile.widget_count
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response! Worked perfectly. (I had earlier tried putting the .select in the wrong place)

Comment: while it works fine on SQLITE3,  Postgres (Heroku) throws an error: (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "widgets.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function). replaced count(*) with count(widgets.id) and still works on SQLITE still throws same err on Postgres. I had thought using the rails activerecord abstractions would prevent that dbase-specific issues.

Comment: FWIW we're using the postgres 9.1 on heroku (the new basic plan)

Comment: It looks like Postgres is stricter about selecting columns in the joined table. You can get around this by not selecting `*` but rather `user_profiles.*`, so long as you don't need anything from the joined table (widgets) other than the count. I've updated my answer.

Comment: BINGO! Thank you. That was a very educational help you provided!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count method, with the :group argument : [count](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000292)

That should look something like :

```
UserProfile.joins(:widgets).order(:name).count(:id, :group => 'user_profiles.id')
```

Comment: This just returns a hash mapping the `UserProfile` ID to the widget count for that particular `UserProfile`. The OP was asking for a way to include the count in the original query, so that all `UserProfile` attributes are returned in addition to the count.